# How I can use MapMyIndia in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapmyindia-api

I can't use MapMyIndia in kotlin, I need to know how I can install it.

Now in my code I got this:

**Project level build.gradle**

```
maven {
            url 'https://maven.mapmyindia.com/repository/mapmyindia/'
        }
```

**App level dependency build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.mapmyindia.sdk:mapmyindia-android-sdk:6.8.2'
```

But when I want to use anything with MapMyIndia on my activity or xml I got none about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one more place where you should import the.

in `settings.gradle` `Project Settings` and
should look something like this

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.mapmyindia.com/repository/mapmyindia/' }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "This is Sparta"
include ':app'
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! Yes the problem was i need the maven in the second repositories